# Merge rows based on duplicate values in 3 columns

Tags: r

I am merging duplicate rows based on 3 columns of a dataframe. But i want to match only the numerical value and then consolidate all duplicate records. In the example below I want to merge information for record id 1 row 1 and 3 because value for columns names, and numerical value in C:CR is the same. Notice the desired output has value "1" in both last two columns. If the value in any of the last two columns is 1 then it should replace 0

Mydata<-

```
id  name    C   P   CR  R   Cl
1   ABC b.123 V>N   p.8224 L>Z  abc1: 112345    1   0
1   TYZ b.456 A>B   p.224 L>Z   abc2: 112346    1   0
1   ABC b.V123 N    p.L8224Z    abc1:112345 0   1
2   TYZ b.456 A>B   p.224 L>Z   abc2: 112346    1   0
2   ABC b.V123 N    p.L8224Z    abc1:112345 1   0
```

Desired output

```
id  name    C   P   CR  R   Cl
1   ABC b.123 V>N   p.8224 L>Z  abc1: 112345    1   1
1   TYZ b.456 A>B   p.224 L>Z   abc2: 112346    1   0
2   TYZ b.456 A>B   p.224 L>Z   abc2: 112346    1   0
2   ABC b.V123 N    p.L8224Z    abc1:112345 1   0
```

My code:

```
Mydata %>% 
group(id, name) %>%
distinct(C:CR, .keep_all= TRUE)
```

Comment: What is the rule governing the last 2 columns? How do you decide to keep the values of P and R for the first row while discarding the values for the third row?

Comment: If the value in any of the last two columns is 1 then it should replace 0

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

This produces the output you are looking for:

```r
Mydata |> 
  group_by(id, name) |> 
  summarise(
    across(c(C, P, CR), first),
    across(c(R, Cl), max),
    .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>      id name  C         P          CR               R    Cl
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 ABC   b.123 V>N p.8224 L>Z abc1: 112345     1     1
#> 2     1 TYZ   b.456 A>B p.224 L>Z  abc2: 112346     1     0
#> 3     2 ABC   b.V123 N  p.L8224Z   abc1:112345      1     0
#> 4     2 TYZ   b.456 A>B p.224 L>Z  abc2: 112346     1     0
```

If you need to heed the numeric values in the C, P and CR for determining duplicate rows:

```r
Mydata |> 
  mutate(across(C:CR, \(x) str_extract(x, "[0-9]+"))) |> 
  group_by(id, name, C, P, CR) |> 
  summarise(
    across(R:Cl, max),
    .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>      id name  C     P     CR        R    Cl
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 ABC   123   8224  1         1     1
#> 2     1 TYZ   456   224   2         1     0
#> 3     2 ABC   123   8224  1         1     0
#> 4     2 TYZ   456   224   2         1     0
```